# Non-blocking ruby UNIXSocket

Tags: ruby, sockets, eventmachine, celluloid

*Preamble: Obviously, I am too stupid.*

I want to expose a simple `UNIXSocket` in Ruby that accepts a single command from connecting clients without blocking further connections while processing until the socket is closed (which the STDLIB socket does) including a timeout for clients that do not send any command within X seconds. What I also want is to `Etc.getpwuid(socket.getpeereid.first).name`, or: Get the username of the user connecting to that socket.

Because the default `UNIXSocket` is blocking all further connections, I have tried to do it with EventMachine and Celluloid:

**EventMachine:**
Multiple connections work like a charm, but there is no way to access the client's `UID`. Also, even though you can set a client timeout, the docs do not tell anything about when this will actually be triggered. Particularily frustrating about this experience: Some methods on `EventMachine` (like `get_peername`) are not documented on any of the googleable API docs, because they are hidden inside the native extensions. Unfortunately, there is no equivalent of `getpeereid` in EventMachine even in the C-Code, so I eventually bailed on this.

**Celluloid:** I opened a regular UNIXSocket and then passed any opened connections to an `async` Celluloid listener. This kept accepting connections as well, but when I tried to end the server process the  Celluloid threads were not able to shut down (`Terminating X actors`), even though I did properly `socket.close` and `Actor.current.terminate` inside my `listen` method (called via `async.listen`). Only thing that remedied this was `kill -9`. Because the docs of Celluloid told me so, I also tried the [`celluloid-io` echo server example](https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid-io/blob/master/examples/echo_unix_client.rb), but that gave me the same result that needed `kill -9`.

I've been thinking about firing up my own handler thread solution but those would be lacking the automatic timeout, and I was hoping someone would already have solved this seemingly basic problem.

I hope I am missing something here. As of now my impression is that Unix Sockets on Ruby are missing the most basic ingredients :/

Comment: Can you post your code for EventMachine & Celluloid?

Comment: I can't help much here but for your own handler thread solution lacking timeout, ruby has a timeout module http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson I put down three simple examples here: https://gist.github.com/4181353

Comment: @bjhaid Good idea, I completely forgot about that. Maybe I should just go with the self-built option for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: And another update: With timeout it works pretty nicely. I added an example to my gist. Still wondering if I am missing some obvious things from the EM/Celluloid examples.